# Failed to establish a new connection, could not find a version that satisfies the requirement soupsieve Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

I'm trying to install the beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (Beautiful Soup) on my Windows 64-bit machine from [here](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#files) but I'm getting the below error as shown in the screenshot. I should also note that I am using python 3.7.5.

[image]

I know there are many tips online on how to potentially resolve this issue, but I have done a few and still am not getting any luck.

**Manually run setup.py**

In the same page as linked above, there is a beautifulsoup4-4.8.2.tar.gz which I have unzipped. Within that folder, there is a `setup.py` file, which I have executed using `python setup.py install`, but I am getting the same error as the above screenshot.

**Update pip3**

I have also tried to run `pip3 install --upgrade pip` to upgrade my pip version, so that I can then run `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`, but once again, I am getting the same error. I should note that access to the internet is restricted and I am not able to install any package.

**Other files**

What I am most confused about is that I've followed the exact same procedure to install packages on this machine before, and have done so successfully. For example, I have run `pip3 install XlsxWriter-1.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl` from a package that I have download from [here](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/#files) and that has worked fine (you'll notice that the extension is the same as the Beautiful Soup package in addition to the "none-any" which I believe can be run on any x-bit machine).

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: connect to `vpn` and try to install. it's seems the issue is due to some restrictions by your `ISP`

Comment: Thank you. Would you have any other suggestions if I can't connect to a VPN?

Comment: Does your machine have internet connectivity usually? Is there a firewall in place? Can you reach other addresses or IPs? Did you try again after some time (>30 min)?

Comment: @Adam to be able to confirm your issue [click-here](https://ms-python.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-python/python/2019.8.29288/1565127378610/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Default) and tell me if you do see a `Python` logo or not ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes I always have internet connectivity. I've also been able to install packages from PyPI through the same way previously (an example is my question post)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I am able to see the Python logo.

Comment: @Adam so it's not a `DNS` issue, rest assured that it's sort of block by your `ISP`. try `vpn` such as `hotspotshield`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη thanks. Is there a reason why I'd be able to install a package through the same way but another I can't?

Comment: @Adam are you able to install any package currently from `Pypi` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη yes I have installed multiple packages so far including `XlsxWriter-1.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, `xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, `lxml-4.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` and `pdfkit-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209374/discussion-between--c-and-adam).

Comment: @Adam, don't use network proxies or VPN tunnels that you know nothing of. If the connection issues persist then download the wheels and their dependencies one by one directly from pypi.org with your browser (or curl, or whatever). Have you tried augmenting the timeouts or the number of retries? Have you simply tried reinstalling pip (`path/to/python -m pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed pip`) or even _Python_? Have you checked that you don't have SSL issues?

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for your input. Could you let me know how to download the wheels and their dependencies one by one? Typically, the pip commands to install/upgrade do not work. I have tried to upgrade pip using `pip3 install --upgrade pip` but that did not work either.

Comment: Well obviously, as it is readable in the error message, pip is now trying to install _soupsieve_, most likely because it is a dependency of _beautifulsoup_, so go to https://pypi.org and search for [_soupsieve_](https://pypi.org/project/soupsieve/) then go to ["_download files_"](https://pypi.org/project/soupsieve/#files) to find a distribution compatible with your environment, in this case the [_wheel_ (`*.whl` file)](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/cf/ea245e52f55823f19992447b008bcbb7f78efc5960d77f6c34b5b45b36dd/soupsieve-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl) should be good enough. And so on.

Comment: But you need to find and fix the root cause of your issue: your connection issues. If I were you I'd just reinstall Python from scratch to get a clean slate. And the command you apparently executed is not the right way to update _pip_, especially not on Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I found the command to update pip online. Could you perhaps let me know which one is the correct one in that case? Also, what would reinstalling Python from scratch do? Do you think the connectivity issues may be because of the Python version installed?

Comment: I gave you already the command I believe is the best to update _pip_, so study it and then you are free to use whichever you want. You need to manage to constrain the issue to something. If you say you are able to do the connections via the browser but not with Python or _pip_, then maybe the issue lies with Python or _pip_. You say it used to work, so maybe something has been compromised fairly recently. So maybe restarting with a clean slate by reinstalling Python is a good idea. Only you can decide and effectively help yourself figuring out how to fix this. We can only give ideas.

Comment: @sinoroc downloading soupsieve worked perfectly, thank you! If you'd like, please post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Adam, no because it doesn't seem to actually solve the issue in the question, it just goes around it. You need to seriously look into it. What causes the issue? Do you have misconfigured DNS settings, network proxy, VPN tunnel, firewall, etc.?

Comment: @sinoroc it's hard to say as this is within an enterprise so I'm unsure how all of that is configured.

Comment: @Adam You can at least check the parts that are local to your machine. You say it's accessible via the browser so, why shouldn't Python be able to access it? Add the outputs of `path/to/python -m pip config list` and `path/to/python -m pip debug` to your question. Check if you have `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables configured and if yes what their values are. Maybe talk to your colleagues (IT department).

Answer (score -1):

seems that some websites are blocked in your region, while this package happens to store data in one of this sites.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl --proxy="my_proxy_name:port"
```

pickup proxy from those:

```
111.118.128.140:41344
183.88.212.184:8080
180.210.201.55:3129
```

Comment: How should that help? It doesn't seem to be a regional block since the user said they have access to download a distribution of the project from the website directly via browser. Why should anyone trust these IP addresses and ports you are providing?

Comment: @sinoroc feel free to use your own proxy server. i didn't asked you or anyone to trust the proxy server. even though there's a lot of known sources confirming that using pip with proxy will not harm your device. good luck